# Xcode 15 - Device Logs Button Missing

Tags: xcode

Trying to resymbolicate a crash file in Xcode and per their instructions (which worked in Xcode 14):

[image: Documentation]

But, the button is missing in XCode 15 Devices and Simulators:

[image: Button Missing]

Where did it go? When I click "Open Recent Logs" it has me open a folder, and even if there are logs in there Xcode forces me to open them in an app (which isn't very useful)...any ideas the "right" way to do this?

Comment: From the Open Recent Logs button, you can browse to your crash file and select it, then select the project you want to open it with, and it will open in Xcode's debug panel, but I haven't been able to make any sense of that interface, especially since the addresses from my app are still not symbolicated.